# BC30521 error on opening a form VS 2017 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a vb.net winforms project and after opening a form that has code that has the following line

Dim ChildForm As frmItemInstallation = New frmItemInstallation

I am getting the following error message:

Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' is most specific for these arguments:    'Public Sub New()': Not most specific.    'Friend Sub New()': Not most specific

I wasn't getting this in the past, just started when I reopened the project to make changes

this is on an existing form in the project, if I create a new form, I don't get the error message

I am using VS 2017 runtime is 4.6.1

Any help would greatly be appreciated

Public Class frmInventory
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

```
#Region " Windows Form Designer generated code "

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call

    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the constructor(s) of this class and where that line is found?

Comment: You have overloaded the “New” declaration and/or you have more than one Sub called “New” (with the same parameters or without parameters). However activate Option Strict On to have compiler errors out.

Comment: I pulled a backup copy of the project and it compiled just fine,I have Option Strict off by default. Thanks for the replies

Comment: Never a good idea to turn of option strict.